# Is finding the (multiplicative) inverse of an element in a field always easy?

Tags: field-theory

If $\mathbb F$ is a field then for each $x\in\mathbb F$ there is some $y\equiv x^{-1}\in\mathbb F$ such that $xy=1$.

In standard fields such as $\mathbb Q,\mathbb R,\mathbb C$, finding such an inverse is relatively easy. Of course, in $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ "finding an inverse" would mean to use a numerical algorithm to approximate it within a given error.

Are there fields in which this doesn't work? In other words, can a field $\mathbb F$ be such that actually finding the inverse of a given element is hard?
I'm aware that "hard" can mean different things here, but I'm not fixing a specific notion of efficiency because I don't know enough about what the answers might be. I'm mostly looking for examples in which finding the inverse is "non-trivial", for some "natural" notion of non-trivial.

I suppose it is possible that the question really boils down to the analogous question for abelian groups (is there always an "easy" algorithm to find the inverse of a given element in an abelian group?). But then again, maybe the additional (!) structure of a field makes a division algorithm easier, so the problems might not be the same.

Comment: For fields of the form $F(a) $ where $a$ is algebraic over $F$, the inverse can be found out using the method of finding GCD of polynomials.

Comment: I am currently not able to find an example, but there may be ways of constructing a "complicated" field as the quotient of some ring $R$ by a sufficiently complex maximal ideal $m$ of $R$.